# CakePHP: Saving a translation saves the translated field in the original table, why?

Tags: cakephp, translation, multilingual

I'm using Translate behavior.

Here's the scenario: I save a translation on model 'Content' with the
language Japanese.

Then I check the corresponding table 'contents' in my database and I see that my 'title' and 'body' fields are changed to the translated inputs (in Japanese). My English (and Japanese) content is saved in the content_i18ns table.

Everything in my views is still in English so it's all fine. I'm just
concerned why my 'contents' table is updated with the translated input.
It's just scary that it might cause errors in the future.

Is this ok? Am I doing something wrong or is this a normal behavior with CakePHP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal.

Everything that you save will get saved in the contents table in the language you are currently using on the page. + it will get saved in the i18n table.

It won't cause any problems, you won't loose data, and if you use the Translate behavior according to the (cook)book than your pages will be fetched in the correct language (since the results will be fetched making a join of the tables contents and i18n (or the custom table that you have defined) and the data fields will be updated corresponding to the language you have set).

Comment: wow thanks for the time in answering my question. i'm relieved that somehow someone else thinks it's okay :)

Comment: The reason being that Translate is merely a behavior that adds the translation functionality, but it does not block/prevent the model from saving/updating its data to the main table.

Answer (score 1):

Drop fields 'title' and 'body' from Your 'contents' table:)

Comment: Is that a proper solution? I'm thinking about making CakePHP not update the 'Content' table with the latest translated input.

Comment: This is actually the correct thing to do, it says so here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1331/Defining-the-Fields